# What is the formal definition of monster model?

Tags: definition, model-theory

What is the formal definition of a monster model for a theory? I have read that term in many model theory books, but I have never seen a rigorous definition of it. Is there even a rigorous definition of it, and if so, what is the definition?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2818402/705222) may be useful.